# Using a MatchEvaluator delegate to generate a list without using class variables?

Tags: c#, regex

**Background:** I'm trying to generate a list of references from a page that has references throughout, and replace the reference markup with HTML.

I'm working in C#

Text looks something like:

```
The dog ate 3 cats and felt ill <ref name="something">http://cateater.com</ref>
```

I'd like to use the Regex.Replace method to replace all the `<ref>`s, pushing them into a Hash that I can later render as a list of references.

**Problem:** it looks like the way to run code during the replace operation is to use a 'MatchEvaluator Delegate' that takes in a Match object, but doesn't seem like it can take other parameters.

The [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) uses a class variable to accomplish this, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using XML tags, is there a reason the source document can't be processed as an XML DOM?  Using XSLT would be a lot easier than a RegEx in that case.

If not then it is possible to effectively a paramatize the MatchEvaluator Delegate by using an anonymous function:-

```
MatchEvaluator evaluator = delegate(Match m)
{
    // code to return replacement
    // this code uses and modifies lookups
}

Dictionary<string, string> lookups = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sOutput = someRegex.Replace(sInput, evaluator);
```

Comment: I wish! the source is a mix of HTML, wiki markup and other stuff like these <ref> elements.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get list of references:

```
var srcmatches = Regex.Matches(src, "<ref .*?>(.*?)</ref>");

List<string> refs = srcmatches.OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].ToString()).ToList();
```

first it matches for `<ref>` tags, then it queries the content of the tag and converts it into list of strings.